# Clickable HTML link in QGIS print composer pdf export?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

According to qgis help files [here](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html):

> 'Labels can be interpreted as html code: check the checkbox Render as HTML. You can now insert a url, an clickable image that link to a web page or something more complex.'

And yet, my label with the contents:

```
<a href="http://google.com">google</a>
```

produces a pdf that's rendered with 'google' in blue text like a link but it's not clickable.

Is it possible to have clickable links in the output? And if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related question and answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/362251/35561

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: for a more recent thread on this topic, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/362251/35561

---

It seems like this is currently not possible

I couldn't find a feature request for this on the [QGIS bug tracker](https://duckduckgo.com?q=qgis+pdf+hyperlink+site%3Ahub.qgis.org) with a quick search. For more info on how feature requests are handled, see [How to effectively get things changed in QGIS?](http://nyalldawson.net/2016/08/how-to-effectively-get-things-changed-in-qgis/)

Comment: I might try adding that feature. Much better with Python then c++ personally, but I'll have a look. SVG export should be a simple one to fix. The document already declares xlink, but then fails to include the text in <xlink> tags.

Comment: Has this been fixed in v3?

Comment: I'm also interested to know if this is fixed. I'd like to have the hyperlink to an anchor on the second page, but I'm thinking that won't work if a general URL won't work.

Comment: Not fixed to my knowledge as I've encountered the issue in QGIS 3.10. See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/19117 for tracking about the issue

Answer (score 0):

Correctly the syntax should be:

```
<a href="url"> link_text </a>
```

In the QGIS layout, this syntax is ignored as there is no distinction between the url part and the link_text part. In fact if you type :

```
<a href> www.qgis.org</a>
```

it's the same thing, but it works.