# Exporting PDF from QGIS Print Layout including clickable hyperlinks

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer, pdf, hyperlink

I am having difficulties to export a PDF from QGIS 3.4 (having the same issue in 3.12 though) print layout with a clickable hyperlink. Looking at https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html (The label item -> main properties) this should be possible since QGIS 2.8.

> Labels can be interpreted as HTML code: check checkbox Render as HTML.
>   You can now insert a URL, a clickable image that links to a web page
>   or something more complex.

I simply want to add a text box below my map including a clickable hyperlink controlled by atlas. I added `<a href="link">Click me</a>` and set the label box as "Render as HTML". I also tried to achieve this by adding a HTML Frame instead of a text box, but still no luck.

The text/link is not clickable when opening the PDF in Adobe Acrobat or other software. During the export I tried both options: Text export as path and as object. Also I tried to force the export as vector. What am I missing?

[This related question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222740/clickable-html-link-in-qgis-print-composer-pdf-export) was asked before the release of QGIS 2.8 and the accepted answer is outdated as well.

This is how the attributes look like: 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 2:

As you can notice, only the actual link (URL) of the blue highlighted text actually works as a link; the text before that ("this is a link") does not.

I saved the created QGIS project dummy_atlas together with the polygon-layer as Geopackage for you - than you can try how this works on your computer. Also the pdf-Atlas generated from this project is uploaded as well - find all the files here: 
https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/SDw7YIyjbpxclDs

[image]

So as a conclusion (see comments below): this is a link is not clickable, but the part with the url is. Clickable hyperlinks in pdfs seem to be possible in QGIS right now only for the URL-part, not for other texts.

Update 1:

You should be able to use both versions, see screenshot:

Version 1: `<a href="[% "link" %]">Click me</a>`

Version 2: `<a href=[% "link" %]>Cick Me</a><br>`

[image]

In my case, it works. See the dummy-atlas I exported in pdf here:
https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/lJp5OlR4pyOoQfs

If you open the pdf in your default pdf-viewer ([SumatraPDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html) in my case), both links work perfectly - not if the pdf is shown in Firefox. Test my pdf and tell if the links work. If not, it means it could be a problem in your pdf-viewer. If it works: are you sure you have set the atlas-configuration correctly (see screenshots):

[image]

[image]

In my case, the final slash / in the URL created a problem, so I changed the links in the attribute-table from `http://www.url.org/` to `http://www.url.org`

But this seems to be another problem, not connected to your problem.

---

Original answer:

The correct syntax is:

```
<a href="[% "AttributeFieldContainingHyperlink" %]">Click me</a>
```

You can use the expression editor, available below the text-field to automatically generate the correct syntax, selecting there the field from your layer under fields and values.

You should see your links highlighted (blue, underlined, the typical hyperlink-style) in the print composer.

Comment: They are highlighted as links, but unfortunately they are still not clickable. Also when trying other software than Adobe Acrobat to open the pdf.

Comment: can you share a screenshot, including the text in the label as well as the "code" you use to define the link?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Second example looks good, in the first one, there are missing quotation marks before and after [ ]. What if you export this atlas - the second link does not work? How does the relevant part of your pdf look like?

Comment: So the text appears styled as a link but does not react like that. However, below you have "active link" and there, the link seems to work. How did you realize that?

Comment: Updated my answer, see above: do the links in my pdf work on your machine?

Comment: Update 2, see above

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts! Did I understand your second update correctly: `this is a link` is not clickable, but the part with the url is? Then it is the same for me. I now have also tried different pdf readers, and everyone behaves the same, at least with the `this is a link` part. So as a conclusion we can say that clickable hyperlinks in pdfs the way I wanted (`this is a link` as clickable text) are simply not possible to create with QGIS? Just the workaround by writing the URL as full (https://www.gis.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Exactly, that seems to be the conclusion. So it's an issue in QGIS - maybe there will be a fix in a future version

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, even if it does not solve your problem.I'm not quite sure if this could be considered a bug as it is not standard html-behaviour or if it is intentionally implemented that only the actual URL is clickable. Maybe worth reporting a bug?

Comment: Still another idea, a workaround for the moment: you can add another textfield under your "click me" textfield - in the textfield beneath, insert the actual hyperlink stryled in html showing the URL, but in the same color as the background of the page, e.g. white - and on top of that you place your "clik me" text. Just tried it, this works when exporting as a pdf. Code could look like this:
<STYLE type="text/css">
a { color: white; }
</STYLE>
<a  href="http://www.your_url.org">http://www.your_url.org</a>