# Clickable label (HTML, Link) in PDF export (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, pdf, html, qgis-print-layouts

I need to export a (GEO)PDF - overview map with bounding boxes - with clickable links in every bounding box.

I tried to simply export a PDF with html-links as text labels, but as you can see in the screenshot of my PDF below, the HTML syntax is not interpreted as link[image]

I also tried simple links like: `<a href>www.qgis.org</a>`

This solution works on clickable text field links (rendered as HTML) but does not match my needs:
[Exporting PDF from QGIS Print Layout including clickable hyperlinks](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354249/exporting-pdf-from-qgis-print-layout-including-clickable-hyperlinks)

Even this post is not helping me: [Clickable HTML link in QGIS print composer pdf export?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222740/clickable-html-link-in-qgis-print-composer-pdf-export)

Comment: You have text-labels overlayed over your map? Than you have to check the box "render as html" to make the html-tags disappear an only show the link - this seems not to be the case in your screenshot. However, as stated in the posts linked by you in the moment it seems to be possible to create only links of the actual URL, not of any other text. Workaround: create another text label containing the URL formatted as link, see the last comment here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354249/exporting-pdf-from-qgis-print-layout-including-clickable-hyperlinks

Comment: A  text field rendered as HTML is not what im looking for. I need a link für every single rectangle in my map.

Comment: have you already perhaps just tried to insert the actual link as a text and not as html? like `only http://URL.com/7025` just to see how it works?

Comment: @MAP Does this pdf fit your needs? https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YvLNlTfL2bQyLp6uRNQYgjxKfhB1RfkH

Answer (score 5):

**This method is software dependent and may not work with some PDF readers.**

**Tested with Acrobat Reader DC (OS: Windows 10).**

To create a PDF file with clickable links inside polygons, just save the links as text in text field and create labels using this field.

You must also set the option `Always export text as text objects` when exporting to PDF. Here is an example [pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YvLNlTfL2bQyLp6uRNQYgjxKfhB1RfkH). If you use acrobat reader to view PDF - hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button when click on the text.

Also you can change the label formatting if you want it to looks like a real URL ([blue and underlined](https://no_link_here)).

[image]

Comment: @MAP Answer updated

Comment: I believe the question is asking for a solution to create text links using arbitrary text, such as [this](https://stackexchange.com), rather than just printing the URL like `https://stackexchange.com`

Comment: @Jake The example PDF file the contains clickable text. So it is a link. Also you can change the text formatting if you want it to looks like a real URL (blue and underlined). Probably the author of the question should clarify what specific result he wants to get.

Comment: I did like you explained: but the links are still not clickable. Could you provide some screenshots?

Comment: @MAP Sure: https://ibb.co/BjFv88v

Comment: @MAP You may also need QGIS project with test dataset: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1E1E00zzpogiCcJQnwHZoGcO_J-UUUCHi

Comment: For any reason the links in your PDF/Project are not working on my machine. I'm running Ubuntu (18.04) and tested with several PDF-Viewer and Browser like MuPDF, Xournal, LibreOffice, Firefox, Chromium... please could anyone try the PDF from Comrade Che on it's Linux-Machine?

Comment: When I understand it correctly this solution is just that some PDF "Readers" (like Acrobat Reader DC and in my case Chrome Internet Browser) interprets texts matching a pattern (like "http://" or "www") as links. Other readers don't because it's not coded as a hyperlink in the PDF.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately , there is a known problem associated with the task you are trying to realise and the QGIS development team is working on it.

For now, the issue is considered " a won't fix " because of how the underlying libraries (QT) export data to GeoPDF.

You can read and follow the issues on QGIS Github at these two addresses:

[Issue 35172](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/35172)

[Issue 29888](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29888)