# Creating relative hyperlinks in QGIS PDF output

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, pdf, hyperlink

I am attempting to add text labels in the composer that will result in clickable relative hyperlinks in the PDF output.

Adding a text label, ticking "Render as HTML" and adding [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) results in a clickable hyperlink from the PDF to Google. However, I'm struggling to generate a clickable relative hyperlink in the PDF. I'm aware the format of a relative path needs to use `\` rather than `/`. I've even attempted to wrap it in the following HTML code: Link but does not help.

How do I create a clickable relative hyperlink in the PDF output please?

Two related questions are:
[Clickable HTML link in QGIS print composer pdf export?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222740/clickable-html-link-in-qgis-print-composer-pdf-export)

[Creating Mapbook with Hyperlink texts in PDF using QGIS Atlas?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140528/creating-mapbook-with-hyperlink-texts-in-pdf-using-qgis-atlas)

I've tried this in QGIS 3.0.3

Answer (score 2):

Not possible, unfortunately. PDF definitely [supports relative links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800596/relative-file-links-in-pdf-files) but there is a known issue in QGIS which prevents HTML links in general from performing as expected.

The [issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/35172) is marked as "won't fix" because it is inherited from the QT library rather than a problem with QGIS itself.

As a workaround, your best bet is probably to use a separate PDF editor to add links manually once the document has been exported. If you need to handle a large number of maps/pages with links based on attributes, consider an InDesign-based workflow with a [data merge](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/data-merge.html) to automatically add links to each page.

Answer (score 0):

You should to use variable **@project_folder** in expresion for action.

Type=**Python**

Action text=

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl;
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView;

myWV = QWebView(None);
myWV.load(QUrl("file:///[% @project_folder || '/' || "link" %]"));
myWV.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm unsure how adding this action will result in a composer text label that is a clickable relative hyperlink in the PDF output. However, I'm intrigued by your answer. Am I right in thinking that a layer feature could be a clickable hyperlink in the PDF output? This would actually be my preferred method but I didn't this this was possible.

Comment: Ups, sorry, now i read slowly your question and i see that I been confused.